# retrofit2 with 2 multiparts - JSON and File is failed

Tags: retrofit2, content-type, multipart

I'm trying to call an external ReST service.

retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
okhttp = "3.14.9"

This is the Retrofit interface as I define it:

```
  @Multipart
  @POST("orgs/{orgUuid}/patients/{patientId}/documents")
  Call<DocUploadRes> uploadDocForPatient(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                         @Path("orgUuid") String orgUuid,
                                         @Path("patientId") Integer patientId,
                                         @Part("metadata") RequestBody metadata,
                                         @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

My Client call is as follow:

```
RequestBody metadataBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), content);

MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","Safereport", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), file.getBytes()));

Response<DocUploadRes> response = pccPatientRestApi.uploadDocForPatient(getBearerAuthHeader(pccAccessToken), pccOrgUuid, patientId, jsonPart, filePart).execute();
```

When I'm running this code with retrofit I'm getting Bad Request from the server with:
**status":"400","title":"Bad Request.","detail":"File type is not supported"**

But when I run the same service from postman it working successfully with the following http request sent:

```
POST /api/public/preview1/orgs/E58A8604-38F2-4098-879E-C6BCC6D01EB8/patients/372842/documents HTTP/1.1
Host: connect2.pointclickcare.com
Authorization: Bearer iy8OUOVa46oxaYRMVYlRApqDW00m:2Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/C:/Users/user/Desktop/RosieConnect-20-API-User-Manual-Ver-07172018.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

{"documentCategory":1,"documentName":"Safebeing Report","effectiveDate":"2020-05-26T08:03:49.895Z"}
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

[image: postman success request]

It seems to me that retrofit doesn't send the 'application/pdf' in the Content-Type header of the file @Part... how can it be fixed?

Any idea will be very much appreciated!

-- Update ---
It appears the the file extension is mandatory.
Problem solved by adding .pdf to the file name

```
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","report.pdf", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), file.getBytes()));
```

Comment: Use `RequestBody` type instead of `MultipartBody.Part` for `metadata` and try.

Comment: I tried using RequestBody - same error result.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and show us the server part code? And also, the updated Retrofit code part?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have the server side code ( it is third party ). I will update the question. thanks for trying to help!!

Comment: @Shashanth question was updated

Comment: The error states that the file format is not supported. Either that API does not support PDF file upload or the file gets corrupted while uploading. And also, do not use `file.getBytes()` while preparing multipart data. Just use `file`. Have you tested the API in Postman? Does it work? If it works with Postman, please post the screenshots.

Comment: I tried with postman and it works with pdf file. I added the logging from postman in the question. As you can see it passing Content-Type: application/pdf.

I have also tried with a file object instead of file.getBytes() , but the error is the same.

Comment: I can't see your edits (today's edits). I asked you to post the Postman **screenshots** so that we see how you're passing parameters, URL (you can hide the domain or IP if you don't want to show us but we need endpoint), and the field names, etc. Just the log is not enough.

Comment: @Shashanth Just upload the image from postman. You can see response 201, with a json contains the documentId. This is the expected result. thank again!

Comment: problem solved! 
The issue was that I was missing the .pdf file extension! 
With the code everything works:

            MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","Safereport.pdf", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), file.getBytes()));